# How to define environment variables in a VS solution and use them in csproj files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to define user environment variables in a Visual Studio solution. Then I would like to use them in the project files. For example:

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(MyUserVar)\MyProject.csproj">
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the VS property sheet.

1. Go to the `Property Manager` tab if it's not highlighted yet.
2. Double click on the newly created property sheet.
3. Go to the `User Macros` node and press the `Add Macro` button.  Insert name to the value field as you'd like and `set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment`.

[image]

Detailed step-by-step instructions can be referred here: https://sites.google.com/site/pinyotae/Home/visual-studio-visual-c/create-user-defined-environment-variables-macros

Comment: It seems to work in C++ projects but in my case, all projects are C#. Is there another option?